# Bootstrap 4.0 dropdown bug on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've came across a really weird compatibility issue, i'm using a dropdown for a sidenav menu with bootsrap 4.0 beta, and it works perfectly fine on Firefox, but on chrome I have a problem :

Basically right when the page loads, if you click the dropdown button it will go up as if it had an invisible negative margin-top, but then when you scroll the page just a bit, and you reclick it, the dropdown will display normally ....

Here is a sample of the code i'm using

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
     <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:transparent">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
           <div id="titre">
                 <h1>My Website</h1><br>
           </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="dropdown show">
              <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle ml-md-1" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Choose an option
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 1</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 2</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 3</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 4</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 5</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 6</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 7</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 8</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 9</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item list-group-item">Option 10</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="schedulePanel col-md-8">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" >
            <div id="mydiv">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: learn this `Toggle contextual overlays for displaying lists of links and more with the Bootstrap dropdown plugin.` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score -2):

for dropdown item use html a tag element instead of ul and li element.

```html
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="frontend">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JS</a>
</div>
```

[Example Mytutorialbox html online editor](http://mytutorialbox.com/online_html_js_css_editor/Bootstrap%204%20dropdown%20button/105)

for more detail you can check this tutorial. [Bootstrap 4 button groups](http://mytutorialbox.com/tutorial/bootstrap/basic-bootstrap-4/button-groups/1503149986090)